# Image upload callback in new 3.5 media

Tags: uploads, media, callbacks

I am using new 3.5 media uploader in my theme frontend (base on [this](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) example). It is very simple when you want to do something with images after the `'Select'` button is pressed:

```
file_frame.on('select', function() {
    // Get all attachments
    var attachments = file_frame.state().get('selection').toJSON();

    // Do stuff with attachments
});
```

But what if I want to do something with attachments just after they were upload? Something like:

```
file_frame.on('upload', function() {
    // Do stuff with attachments
});
```

I didn't find anything useful in `'wp-includes/js/media-models.js'` or `'wp-includes/js/media-views.js'`.

I have tried to attach a lot of events found in those files:

```
'add', 'url', 'select', 'ready', 'escapeHandler', 'keydown', 'attach', 'open', 'close', 'escape', 'recordTab', 'updateIndex', 'activate', 'dismiss', 'remove', 'reset', 'uploading', 'deactivate', 'create', 'render', 'change:content', 'scan', 'prepare', 'content:render:upload', 'content:render', 'content', 'updateIndex', 'recordTab', 'change:uploading', 'finish', 'done', 'upload', 'uploaded', 'save', 'saved','change:compat', 'compat'
```

But all these events fires not when I need this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could hook into the add_attachment action: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_attachment

Answer (score 11):

There is a `FileUploaded` event being fired in `wp-includes/js/plupload/wp-plupload.js`.

Alternatively (and propably the better way) you may want extend wp.Uploader with your own success callback .

```
(function($){

    $.extend( wp.Uploader.prototype, {
        success : function( file_attachment ){
            console.log( file_attachment );
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jörn Lund, you are a wizard! Your wp.Uploader.prototype works great! I have been looking for a very long time how can I update the media library after the file has finished loading into the wp media frame. Hats off to you!
Here is my code:

```
$.extend(wp.Uploader.prototype,{
    success: function(file_attachment){
        console.log(file_attachment);
        if(wp.media.frame.content.get() !== null){
            setTimeout(function(){
                wp.media.frame.content.get().collection.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});
            },100);
        }
    }
});
```