# Change default 'file not supported' error message

Tags: media, media-library

Wordpress 4.8

When an unsupported file is attempted to be uploaded via the WP Media Library the following error message is displayed:

**Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.**

Is there a way (eg filter) that will allow this error message to be manipulated, such as:

**Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons. Please ZIP the file and try uploading the ZIP file instead.**

(Obviously support is added to allow ZIP files)

Comment: Looking through the core, there doesn't seem to be any filter, however you could probably use the media upload javascript actions to hook in and add your own... [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92415/image-upload-callback-in-new-3-5-media/131295#131295) may help get you started.

Comment: Thanks @brianjohnhanna, I can confirm that this allows me to obtain the error message, however, this will work when uploading on the **Media > Library** page, but does not work on the **Media > Add New** page. **Media > Add New** wp.Uploader is **typeof:undefined** whereas on **Media > Library** wp.Uploader is **typeof:function**

Comment: Just an FYI: looking at scripts-loader.php, I see the array of error message strings ( `$uploader_l10n` ) is localized to scripts at L312, L315 and L324 via class.wp-scripts.php's `localize()` method. But, see no filter hooks.